# How to reference passed record address in CICS COBOL program?

Tags: cobol, file-access, cics

I am working on a project to convert a mainframe CICS application currently written in HLASM into COBOL.  I have a number of utility programs that will continue to be used -- one of them is a "file access" utility which is accessed via CICS LINK.  This utility takes the necessary input parameters (passed in the commarea) to generate a CICS file request to read a record from a specified file, and passes back the address of the storage area and length of the retrieved record in that same commarea.  In assembler, it was easy to load that address into a register then associate that register with a record map (DSECT) via a `USING` directive.

But how is this best done in COBOL?  Do I use the address passed back in the commarea and somehow associate it with the COBOL record layout so that I can reference a record field directly in the COBOL program?  If so, how?

Or do I have to somehow move the data into a local working storage area?  And then move it back to reflect any updates that may have been made by the COBOL program?  Again, if so, how?

Comment: @NealB's answer is the way to go. In his example LINK-REC is your DSECT. A COBOL data-item with [USAGE] POINTER contains an address. As long as that storage maps to the address, of the data, from the Assembler program, the SET will then associate the data with the LINKAGE SECTION data-description (the DSECT equivalent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CICS COMMAREA declare a variable of type POINTER to hold the address of the record
buffer your utility program will return. For example:

```
  01 COMM-CICS.
     02 COMM-SOME-STUFF PIC whatever...
     02 COMM-REC-BUFF-ADDRESS POINTER.
     02 COMM-REC-BUFF-LENGTH  PIC 9(9) BINARY.
     02....
```

In your COBOL program declare the record layout in the
`LINKAGE SECTION`, for example:

```
  LINKAGE SECTION.
  01 LINK-REC.
     02 LINK-DATA1 PIC X(10).
     02 .....
```

This creates the layout but does not allocate any
storage to it. Upon return from your utility program use the COBOL `SET ADDRESS` verb to
assign the address of the record buffer to the record layout, something like:

```
  SET ADDRESS OF LINK-REC TO COMM-REC-BUFF-ADDRESS
```

Now your COBOL program should be able to address any of the items in the file record by name, for example:

```
  MOVE LINK-DATA1 TO some-other-variable
```

As a check on the returned data area, you can check the length of the buffer against the length of the COBOL record layout using the COBOL `LENGTH OF` verb, for example:

```
  IF LENGTH OF LINK-REC NOT = COMM-REC-BUFF-LENGTH
     raise an error - buffer length does not match record layout
  END-IF
```

A warning though... This probably will not work if the LINK is to a remote machine because they will not be sharing the same address space. I would recommend that you investigate using CICS Channels and Contaners for this sort of thing.

Comment: Excellent - clear explanation and example code!  I had wondered if it was something like this, but could not find any examples to match my exact situation.  Makes sense once you see it. :-)